# SQL how to select multiple columns based on "earlier date" condition

Tags: sql, if-statement, conditional-statements

I am trying to convert the table below using SQL:

```
person_id event1 date1        event2   date2
1         yes    2019-01-01   NULL     NULL
2         NULL   NULL         yes      2019-02-02
3         NULL   NULL         NULL     NULL
4         yes    2019-03-01   yes      2019-03-04
```

Into something like this:

```
person_id  event_overall  date_overall
1          event1         2019-01-01
2          event2         2019-02-02
3          no_event       NULL
4          event1         2019-03-01
```

Basically, if event1 is "yes" and event2 is "NULL, then event1 is shown, and vice versa. If both are "NULL", then "no_event" is shown. If both are "yes", then the earlier date (in the example 2019-03-01 comes before 2019-03-04, so event1 is selected) is shown.

Comment: you might want to look into sql server [pivot](http://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-pivot/)

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: If your DBMS supports the feature use APPLY / LATERAL JOIN.

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
select 
    person_id, 
    case when event1 is null and event2 is null then 'no event' 
    when (event1 is not null and event2 is null) OR date1<date2 then 'event1'
    else 'event2'end event_overall, 
    case when event1 is null and event2 is null then null
    when (event1 is not null and event2 is null) OR date1<date2 then date1
    else date2 end date_overall
 from tbl
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN event1 = 'yes' THEN date1
     WHEN event2 = 'yes' THEN date2
     WHEN (event1 = 'yes' AND event2 = 'yes') THEN IF(date1 < date2, date1, date2)
     WHEN (event1 IS NULL AND event2 IS NULL) THEN 'no_event'
END AS DATE
FROM tb_event_test
```

Comment: yep I have mistaken with mySQL. you can use `AND` instead of `&&`